# Sort and display panel in CP does not show all the fields

Tags: control-panel

When I try to arrange some entry field in the CP's sort and display panel, the panel does not show all the fields in the server version, while it display all the fields in my local version. Although, all the fields are in sync between the two databases.
How can I get all the fields back in the panel?

Thanks for your help.

[image: Here the sort and display panel in my local machine]

[image: Here the sort and display panel in my server machine for the very same entry]